# Sorting disabled select options

Tags: html, css

There is a `select` with `disabled` `option`s. My question is that is there a CSS solution to sort the `option`s? I want to arrange all the `disabled` options to the bottom, and all the enabled `option`s to the top. I've attached a screenshot. The enabled `option`s' color is black, and the `disabled` `option`s' color is light gray.

```
#playground-content select option {
    color: black;
}

#playground-content select option:disabled {
    color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is not possible. if it were in some other format, like a `<ul>` or `<div>`s, then css has more to work with, and can use properties like `float` to influence the sorting, but the limited power that css has over native `<select>` controls is not enough

Comment: Sorting data is outside the realm of what CSS is meant for, but you should be able to hide the disabled elements pretty easily (even though that's not what you want). Otherwise, you'll need some Javascript. You could also look into something like this crazy SASS implementation: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/sorting-function/

Comment: It can be done with Javascript, but where is the fun doing that? Note, that if you remove some elements from the options and put them back, then you will have some problems with the viewport in Chrome, for instance, due to a Chrome bug. (try to remove options and to put them back) So, the only thing left is to effectively exchange the values and the inner texts and the classes and the attributes between the options. This can be done in Javascript, but it is really ugly. A CSS solution would be desirable.

Comment: If `select` were not replaced elements, you could use `select{display:flex; flex-direction:column} option:disabled{order:1}`. But that won't work because replaced elements are outside the scope of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$("#addselect option").each(function (i, val) {
                if ($(this)[i].disabled) {
                    moveDown("selectId");
                }
                else {
                    moveUp("selectId");
                }
 }



   function moveUp(selectId) {
            var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
            var selectOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
            for (var i = 1; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
                var opt = selectOptions[i];
                if (!opt.disabled) {
                    selectList.removeChild(opt);
                    selectList.insertBefore(opt, selectOptions[i - 1]);
                }
            }
        }

        function moveDown(selectId) {
            var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
            var selectOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
            for (var i = selectOptions.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                var opt = selectOptions[i];
                if (opt.disabled) {
                    var nextOpt = selectOptions[i + 1];
                    opt = selectList.removeChild(opt);
                    nextOpt = selectList.replaceChild(opt, nextOpt);
                    selectList.insertBefore(nextOpt, opt);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Loop through your select list

Comment: loop through your select list

for every enabled option move it up 

for every disabled option move it down

Comment: Try to avoid code-only answers (read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303605/4284627)). Please edit your answer to explain your code.